# "And who's finished up the better off?"

Tags: sentence-construction

"I said you chose books and i chose looks," Mrs Wormwood said. "And who's finished up the better off?

Me, of course. I'm sitting pretty in a nice house with a successful businessman and you're left slaving

away teaching a lot of nasty little children the ABC."

these sentences come from the novel Matilda.

and my question is ,  in this sentence "And who's finished up the better off?"

who's =  'who is'  or 'who has'  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Who has*. Mrs. W. claims that she has 'finished up' in a better situation than the person she is talking to.

Comment: but  i found that 'better off'  is adjective,  is it possible that 'finish up' has 'better off ' as object??

Comment: 'better off _person_' is implied.